# Overridden OnException filter always returning status code 500

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to build a **FilterAttribute** that will handle my errors for my **Web API**. Currently it logs the errors to the database, but it always returns a 500 **Internal Server** error no matter what I do.
My filter looks like this:

```
public class LogExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    // Private properties
    private readonly ILogProvider _logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Our default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    public LogExceptionFilterAttribute(ILogProvider logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when an exception has been thrown
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context</param>
    public override async void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        // Get our user
        var requestContext = context.Request.GetRequestContext();
        var user = requestContext.Principal.Identity;

        // Create our response
        var message = await _logger.ErrorAsync(context.Exception, user);
        var statusCode = GetStatusCodeFromException(context);
        var content = new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode);
        //{
        //    Content = new StringContent(message),
        //    StatusCode = statusCode
        //};

        // Assign our response to our context
        context.Response = content;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a status code from an error
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static HttpStatusCode GetStatusCodeFromException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        // Cast the exception as an HttpException
        var exception = context.Exception as HttpException;

        // If there is still an exception, return the code
        if (exception != null)
            return (HttpStatusCode)exception.GetHttpCode();

        // Switch on the exception type
        switch (context.Exception)
        {

            // Not found
            case ObjectNotFoundException ex:
                return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

            // Not implemented
            case NotImplementedException ex:
                return HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;

            // Internal server error
            default:
                return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
}
```

I have put a breakpoint in the **GetStatusCodeFromException** method and verified that the actual status code I should be getting is 501 (Not Implemented) but the return is always 500. I have tried with other status codes too and it is always a 500.

Does someone know how I can actually get it to return a different status code?

### Update

I have found out more.
If I change my OnException method to this:

```
public override async void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{

    // Get our user
    var request = context.Request;
    //var requestContext = request.GetRequestContext();
    //var user = requestContext.Principal.Identity;

    //// Log our error and get the status code
    //var message = await _logger.ErrorAsync(context.Exception, user);
    //var statusCode = GetStatusCodeFromException(context);

    // Create our response
    context.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
}
```

I get a nice 501 error when using postman, but as soon as I uncomment the **requestContext** line, it get an error 500. I think that invoking **GetRequestContext** somehow changes the HttpRequestMessage so that when I invoke **CreateResponse** it always generates a 500.

Anyone know why? Or how to get around it?